# python sending curl request with actual data instead of file

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

If I want to mimic a curl request in python like:

```
curl https:/fake_api.com/extract.do \
    --form account=my_account \
    --form username=my_username \
    --form password=my_password \
    --form uploaded_file=@my_document.xml
```

how would I replicate this request in python if I don't want to actually use a file, but pass the xml from a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `requests` library to achieve this result.
the post method accepts a dictionary `files` containing the filenames as keys and the content as values.
The follow code should work as you expect:

```
import requests
requests.post('https:/fake_api.com/extract.do', 
   data={
      'account': 'my_account',
      'username': 'my_username',
      'password': 'my_password'
   },
   files={'my_file.xml': '<test><a>your content</a></test>'}
)
```