# Send curl request with python

Tags: python, curl, twitter, request

I have a cURL request I copied from the network tracking in devtools and i need to send it regularly using python.

```
curl "https://twitter.com/i/api/1.1/friendships/create.json" -X POST -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Referer: https://twitter.com/not_doxing_myself_lol" -H "x-twitter-auth-type: OAuth2Session" -H "x-twitter-client-language: en" -H "x-twitter-active-user: yes" -H "x-csrf-token: not_doxing_myself_lol" -H "Origin: https://twitter.com" -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin" -H "authorization: Bearer not_doxing_myself_lol" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cookie: guest_id=v1"%"3A163657050970076789; eu_cn=1; g_state={""i_l"":1,""i_p"":1646846243191}; ct0=3e2bfe76f3316083ddf707e3f6d2ac4b152eb3dcf43826b0ba1ece6f753f06094d13fed4f9174f1e08969764643f3e437a53f0395aec99226242af669751adb744a9041981ea32ea94a5b1ca50ab0cd6; kdt=5urnpEaimZUdlLCrrmai56MkZQ3SOiLaHWdkovUw; twid=u"%"3D1267780668546826242; auth_token=not_doxing_myself_lol; night_mode=2; d_prefs=MToxLGNvbnNlbnRfdmVyc2lvbjoyLHRleHRfdmVyc2lvbjoxMDAw; guest_id_ads=v1"%"3A163657050970076789; guest_id_marketing=v1"%"3A163657050970076789; personalization_id=""not_doxing_myself_lol""; dnt=1; _twitter_sess=not_doxing_myself_lol; external_referer=padhuUp37zjgzgv1mFWxJ12Ozwit7owX|0|8e8t2xd8A2w"%"3D; mbox=session#e45db1eeb1cc4444b63b2ac482ea14b5#1648982599|PC#e45db1eeb1cc4444b63b2ac482ea14b5.37_0#1712225539; at_check=true; des_opt_in=Y" --data-raw "include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&include_ext_has_nft_avatar=1&skip_status=1&user_id=not_doxing_myself_lol"
```

request edited to not dox myself

Comment: Try https://curlconverter.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41365275/5644449

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is the code you may refer

```
import requests

url = "https://twitter.com/i/api/1.1/friendships/create.json"

payload='include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&include_ext_has_nft_avatar=1&skip_status=1&user_id=not_doxing_myself_lol'
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Referer': 'https://twitter.com/not_doxing_myself_lol',
  'x-twitter-auth-type': 'OAuth2Session',
  'x-twitter-client-language': 'en',
  'x-twitter-active-user': 'yes',
  'x-csrf-token': 'not_doxing_myself_lol',
  'Origin': 'https://twitter.com',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'authorization': 'Bearer not_doxing_myself_lol',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Cookie': 'guest_id=v1%3A163657050970076789; eu_cn=1; g_state={i_l:1,i_p:1646846243191}; ct0=3e2bfe76f3316083ddf707e3f6d2ac4b152eb3dcf43826b0ba1ece6f753f06094d13fed4f9174f1e08969764643f3e437a53f0395aec99226242af669751adb744a9041981ea32ea94a5b1ca50ab0cd6; kdt=5urnpEaimZUdlLCrrmai56MkZQ3SOiLaHWdkovUw; twid=u%3D1267780668546826242; auth_token=not_doxing_myself_lol; night_mode=2; d_prefs=MToxLGNvbnNlbnRfdmVyc2lvbjoyLHRleHRfdmVyc2lvbjoxMDAw; guest_id_ads=v1%3A163657050970076789; guest_id_marketing=v1%3A163657050970076789; personalization_id=not_doxing_myself_lol; dnt=1; _twitter_sess=not_doxing_myself_lol; external_referer=padhuUp37zjgzgv1mFWxJ12Ozwit7owX|0|8e8t2xd8A2w%3D; mbox=session#e45db1eeb1cc4444b63b2ac482ea14b5#1648982599|PC#e45db1eeb1cc4444b63b2ac482ea14b5.37_0#1712225539; at_check=true; des_opt_in=Y'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```